# SqlDataReader is causing an SqlException in vb.net 2008

Tags: .net, vb.net, sqldatareader, sqlexception

The problem I am having is I keep catching a SQL exception. It's happening in my 'FlexList" class. I've ran the debugger and it is the line of code "Dim mySqlDataReader As SqlDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader" that is breaking it and throwing the error. What am I doing wrong? Any kind of help offered would be EXTREMELY helpful.

Query statement going into the class encountering errors:

```
Public Class MainView
    Private _thatList As New GetClass
    Private _AddEditTerms As New Add_EditWindow
    Private _listManager As New listManager
    Private myQuery As String = _thatList.getAvaliableStatuses
    Private _flexList As New FlexList(myQuery)
'cut out the rest of the code
End Class
```

Class encountering the errors:
    Imports System.Data.SqlClient
    Imports System.Collections.Specialized

```
Public Class FlexList
    Public ReadOnly rows As New List(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))
    Public ReadOnly fields() As String

    Public Sub New(ByRef myQuery As String)
    Dim myConnection As SqlConnection = DataConnection.getProperityDBConnection()
    Dim row As Dictionary(Of String, String)

    Try
        myConnection.Open()
        Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand()
        myCommand.Connection = myConnection
        myCommand.CommandText = myQuery
        Dim mySqlDataReader As SqlDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader

        If mySqlDataReader.HasRows Then
            Dim fieldCount = mySqlDataReader.FieldCount
            ReDim fields(fieldCount - 1)

            mySqlDataReader.Read()
            For i = 0 To fieldCount - 1
                fields(i) = mySqlDataReader.GetName(i)
            Next

            Do
                row = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
                For i = 0 To fieldCount - 1
                    row.Add(mySqlDataReader.GetName(i), IIf(mySqlDataReader.IsDBNull(i), "NULL", mySqlDataReader.GetValue(i).ToString))
                Next
                rows.Add(row)
                row = Nothing
            Loop While mySqlDataReader.Read()

        End If

    Catch ex As SqlException
        MsgBox("Database Error. Please contact you system administor")
    Catch ex As DataException
        MsgBox("Connection Error. Please contact The Delevelopement Team")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("An Unknown Error has occured. Try again and report the error if it persists: " & vbCr & ex.ToString)
    Finally
        myConnection.Close()
    End Try

End Sub

End Class
```

The stored procedure I am using to test this:
    Imports System.Data.SqlClient

```
Public Class Get_Avaliable_Statuses
Public Function getAvailableStatuses()
    Dim connection As SqlConnection = DataConnection.getProperityDBConnection

    Dim insertCommand As New SqlCommand("dbo.ksp_Get_Available_Statuses", connection)
    insertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

    Try
        connection.Open()
        Dim count As Integer = insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        If count > 0 Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    Finally
        connection.Close()
    End Try
End Function
End Class
```

Comment: ...Which line is the error on? I see a possible null reference with `IIf(mySqlDataReader.IsDBNull(i), "NULL", mySqlDataReader.GetValue(i).ToString)`. Even if it's null, it will still evaluate the false part. changing `IIF()` to just `If()` would fix this.

Comment: The question actually answer that : "Dim mySqlDataReader As SqlDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader"

Comment: I hate to ask this, but don't you think the actual exception is pretty important to have included in this question?

Comment: Nevermind my previous comment then (although it's still a good change to make), your problem is in the query text or your connection settings, neither of which are in your code.

Comment: The connection string works. I ran it through vb's built in debugger and no errors were encountered. I also tested the stored procedure I'm using our SQL server just to make sure it works, and it does.

Comment: Adding the stored procedure to the code.

Comment: if this `myCommand.ExecuteReader` errors out, I like to see what's  in  `myCommand.CommandText = myQuery`

Comment: @T.S. I added the where the query statement is coming from. I placed it in the main view window class for testing purposes.

Comment: There is your problem - " [*] " use " * ". Remove square brackets

Comment: @T.S. ... Of course it would be an error like that... Thank you so much for helping. I think I've been looking at it too long. You were a huge time saver. :D

Comment: No problem, we all do it every day. please kindly mark my answer. Thank you

Comment: Unable too until I get 15 rep. Once I do, I will mark it up!

Comment: The FlexList class is flawed in an important way not related to your question. By having a constructor that only accepts an sql string, you force yourself to write code that will be horribly vulnerable to sql injection attacks: you're practically begging to get hacked.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud Noted. I will start getting more accurate with my errors from here on out. Thank you.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Also noted, I thank you. Still learning the ropes and making this program for 1 person internally in the reporting department. She will be the only one using it. 

I will keep that in mind and work on making my code safer. Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is your problem - " [*] " use " * ". Remove square brackets